# extracting a word starting with a specific letter from a string

Tags: php

I want to extract all words starting with `@` in a string with php.

Which way is the best ?

EDIT: I dont want to fetch emails

Thanks

Comment: So spaces delimit the word? Matching `@New York` will fetch `@New`, correct?

Comment: @Pekka yeah i dont want to fetch spaces

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$matches = null;
preg_match_all('/(?!\b)(@\w+\b)/','This is the @string to @test.',$matches)
```

Using [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and taking advantage of a look-ahead for the start of a word (`(?!\b)`) and word delimiter (`\b`), you can achieve this easily. Broken down:

```
/           # beginning of pattern
  (?!\b)    # negative look-ahead for the start of a word
  (         # begin capturing
    @       # look for the @ symbol
    \w+     # match word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 & _)
    \b      # match until end of the word
  )         # end capturing
/           # end of pattern
```

**[demo](http://www.ideone.com/Mp6ox)**

Comment: `$matches = null;` is not needed.

Comment: @codeaddict. I'm aware, but I consider it better practice to know where my variables begin. Though block scope isn't *actually* there, I go between .NET and PHP and like to know where I can expect to see new variables.

Comment: You could also use `\B` instead of `(?!\b)`.

Comment: @Gumbo: Isn'tt hat the opposite of `\b`? In which case it would do the opposite and catch things such as email? or am I off-base on this one?

Comment: BTW is there a way to make that $matches not multi-dimensional array ?

Comment: @Brad Christie: Yes, `\B` is the opposite of `\b` just like `(?!\b)` is. Both assertions say: No word-boundary.

Comment: @Ahmet: `$matches = $matches[1];` ;-) -- @Gumbo: Ah, true. i'm just used to negative look-aheads and excluding it from the grouping, but I see what you mean (unnecessary in this scenario). Good catch.